# RemoveAll only removing foreign key reference

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following model (scaled down of course)

```
public class WorkOrder
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<WorkOrder_Worker> Workers {get; set;}
}

public class WorkOrder_Worker
{
        public int ID {get; set;}

        [ForeignKey("Worker")]
        public int WorkerID { get; set; }

        public virtual AdminProfile Worker { get; set; }

        public virtual WorkOrder WorkOrder { get; set; }
}
```

I have code such as the following:

```
    Context.WorkOrders.Where(a=>a.ID == 1).Workers.RemoveAll();
    Context.SaveChanges();
```

In the database, this is only setting the field "WorkOrder_ID" = NULL instead of deleting the row in the database.  How do I delete the entire row?

Comment: Where is 'WorkOrder_ID' and what does a.ID reference? You should include more model information.

Comment: I added some more info to the model.  a.ID is the Work Order ID.  Yes, I'm calling SaveChanges().   WorkOrder_ID is the field that was created in the database table with Code First.